# SQL - Replace a particular part of column string value (between second and third slash)

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my **SQLServer** DB, I have a table called **Documents** with the following columns:

1. ID - INT
2. DocLocation - NTEXT

**DocLocation** has values in following format:
*'\\fileShare1234\storage\ab\xyz.ext'*

Now it seems these documents are stored in multiple file share paths.
We're planning to migrate all documents in one single file share path called say 'newFileShare' while maintaining the internal folder structure.

So basically  *'\\fileShare1234\storage\ab\xyz.ext'* should be updated to *'\\newFileShare\storage\ab\xyz.ext'*

Two questions:

1. How do I query my DocLocation to extract DocLocations with unique file share values? Like 'fileShare1234' and 'fileShare6789' and so on..
2. In a single Update query how do I update my DocLocation values to *newFileShare* (*'\\fileShare1234\storage\ab\xyz.ext'*  to *'\\newFileShare\storage\ab\xyz.ext'*)

I think the trick would be extract and replace text between second and third slashes.

I've still not figured out how to achieve my first objective. I require those unique file shares for some other tasks.

As for the second objective, I've tried using replace between it will require multiple update statements. Like I've done as below:

```
update Documents  set DocLocation = REPLACE(Cast(DocLocation as NVarchar(Max)), '\\fileShare1234\', '\\newFileShare\')
```

Comment: You really need to change that NTEXT column to NVARCHAR(MAX).  This can be done using stuff: stuff(cast(DocLocation As nvarchar(max)), 3, charindex('\', DocLocation, 3) - 1, 'newFileShare').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following solution based on XML and XQuery.

Their data model is based on ordered sequences. Exactly what we need while processing fully qualified file path: `[position() ge 4]`

When you are comfortable, just run the UPDATE statement by updating the **DocLocation** column with the calculated **result**.

It is better to use `NVARCHAR(MAX)` instead of `NText` data type.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl AS TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, DocLocation NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @tbl(DocLocation) VALUES 
('\\fileShare56789\storage\ab\xyz.ext'),
('\\fileShare1234\storage\ab\cd\xyz.ext'), 
('\\share4567890\w\x\y\z\file.ext');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = '\'
    , @newFileShare NVARCHAR(100) = 'newFileShare';

SELECT ID, DocLocation
    , result = '\\' + @newFileShare + @separator +
        REPLACE(c.query('data(/root/r[position() ge 4]/text())').value('text()[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), SPACE(1), @separator) 
FROM @tbl
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
        REPLACE(DocLocation, @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
        ']]></r></root>' AS XML)) AS t(c);
```

**Output**

```
+----+---------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| ID |              DocLocation              |                result                |
+----+---------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
|  1 | \\fileShare56789\storage\ab\xyz.ext   | \\newFileShare\storage\ab\xyz.ext    |
|  2 | \\fileShare1234\storage\ab\cd\xyz.ext | \\newFileShare\storage\ab\cd\xyz.ext |
|  3 | \\share4567890\w\x\y\z\file.ext       | \\newFileShare\w\x\y\z\file.ext      |
+----+---------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

The first step is fairly easy. If all your paths begin with `\\`, then you can find all the `DISTINCT` servers using `SUBSTRING`. I will make a simple script with a table variable to replicate some data. The value of 3 is in the query and it is the length of `\\` plus 1 since SQL Server counts from 1.

```sql
DECLARE @Documents AS TABLE(
    ID INT NOT NULL, 
    DocLocation NTEXT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO @Documents(ID, DocLocation) 
VALUES (1,'\\fileShare56789\storage\ab\xyz.ext'),
(2,'\\fileShare1234\storage\ab\cd\xyz.ext'), 
(3,'\\share4567890\w\x\y\z\file.ext');

SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING(DocLocation, 3, CHARINDEX('\', DocLocation, 3) - 3) AS [Server] 
FROM @Documents;
```

The results from this are:

| Server |
| --- |
| fileShare1234 |
| fileShare56789 |
| share4567890 |

For the second part, we can just concatenate the new server name with the path that appears after the first `\`.

```sql
UPDATE @Documents 
SET DocLocation = CONCAT('\\newfileshare\',
    SUBSTRING(DocLocation, 3, LEN(CAST(DocLocation AS nvarchar(max))) - 2));

SELECT * FROM @Documents;
```

For some reason I cannot create a table with the results here, but the values I see are this:

```
\\newfileshare\fileShare56789\storage\ab\xyz.ext
\\newfileshare\fileShare1234\storage\ab\cd\xyz.ext
\\newfileshare\share4567890\w\x\y\z\file.ext
```

Answer (score 1):

to get the unique list of shared folder path , you can use this query:

```
SELECT distinct SUBSTRING(DocLocation,0,CHARINDEX('\',DocLocation,3))
from Documents
```

and your update command should work and yes you can merge copuple of replace update but better to run them seperately

```
update Documents  
set DocLocation = REPLACE(DocLocation,'\\fileShare1234','\\newFileShare')
```

but I recommend you always record relative address instead of full path like: `\storage\ab\xyz.ext'`